# How to add a row into a 1-D array with python-numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to add a row into a `1-D array` with a `2-D array` as a result:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random((3,4))
b = np.array([1,2,3])
c = np.append(b, np.transpose(a[:,2]), axis=0)
```

But the result is a `1-D array`:

```
array([ 1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ,  0.77329384,  0.25485223,
    0.56982045])
```

How can I get the expected result:

```
array([1. , 2. , 3.  ,],
      [0.77329384, 0.25485223, 0.56982045])
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> np.vstack((b, np.transpose(a[:,2])))
array([[ 1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ],
       [ 0.14942441,  0.75303451,  0.64617275]])
```